# create github like "label" feature

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0, github

I have noticed on github they allow you to create multiple labels and associate that with an issue, if you want to filter you can filter by label.

How would I go about creating something like this?

I have a task manager, what would I need to store in the database for the labels?

My process (thinkin out aloud): Create a task, allow user who created the task to add a label, this label has to be from a predifined list, so a table called UserLabels - where I can store the labels, I will show the labels from this list when a user wants to add multiple labels to their task.

Do I store the the label ids inside a nvarchar(max) field as an array i.e:
{labelid:5,labelid:6,labelid:900}

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to do this the propper way you'd have a table that maps task ID's to Label ID's. as foreign keys.

This would be the correctly normalised way to do it.

Personally I'd have a field in my task table that contained either a list of label ids or the labels themselves. It would depend on my criteria really.

Comment: wouldnt my database take a massive hit, I could potentially have a massive list of records inside the TaskLabel table? I mean I could limit the tags to 3 per task, that could help massively or even 1 per task

Comment: stackoverflow actually stores the tags in one field, see posts table: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema

Comment: That's how many-to-many relationships tend to work in databases. Like I say, I'd probably have a varchar field with a list of label ID's or Labels